# Indexing array by tuples in Julia?

Tags: arrays, julia

I would like to create (in Julia) a 2 dimensional array Y storing the spherical harmonics Y_lm(x) evaluated at some fixed x, indexed by an integer l>=0 and -l<=m<=l.

How can I create the array Y such that I may **access elements via tuples**, e.g, to access Y_20(x) I would call Y[(2,0)]?

More generally does Julia allow arrays indexed by tuples (x1,...xn) if we don't know anything about the possible range of the xi (like a dictionary, but indexed by tuples of integers instead of strings)?

Comment: I don't entirely understand your last sentence, but what about `CartesianIndex`? It would allow you constructions such as `ind = CartesianIndex((2, 0)); Y[ind]`

Comment: @ginkul I mean for example let's suppose you want to associate some floats to some tuples of integers, but these tuples don't follow any particular pattern. They might be (1,2,3), (-22,45,90), (-11,10,2), etc.

Comment: If I now understand correctly you actually could use `Dict` because you're not forced to have strings as its keys. You could easily write something like this: `d = Dict((2, 0) => 3, (19, -3) => 42)` and access its elements accordingly.

Comment: You might be able to find something in the [SphericalHarmonicsExpansion.jl](https://github.com/hofmannmartin/SphericalHarmonicExpansions.jl) package.

Comment: If it's just a normal 2D array, you can always splat the tuple: `Y[(2,0)...]`. (Of course, you still have to make sure that the indices are valid; `0` generally isn't, unless you're using OffsetArrays.)

Comment: @ginkul ah ok so Dict can use non-string keys, I didn't know that (Julia beginner). great! my question now is, would that be slower than using arrays (if I have to access the values in the dictionary many times)

Comment: @BallpointBen Yes but here I will have e.g., (2,-1) negative values for m. So if I still want to use arrays (dictionaries appear to be slow), there is no easy workaround?

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou assuming your tuples actually correspond to array indices, then you should use the OffsetArrays package

Comment: The real question is: are the ranges of `l` and `m` you want to store contiguous? If so, OffsetArrays is the best choice. Otherwise, there'll be no other option than some kind of dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, that isn't what arrays are "for" in Julia, this is what `Dict` is for. In Julia (and many languages) what is generally meant by an array is something that is indexed by a series of contiguous integer values. (That said, you can implement your own object implementing the Array interface that might work differently...).

A Dict allows for any arbitrary set of indices, that can be any type you want, not just strings. For example:

```
Y = Dict()
Y[(2,0)] = "Hello, World"
println(Y[(2,0)])
```

For your particular problem there may be a more efficient solution, but I don't know enough about spherical harmonics to know what it would be. It would be worth looking at the [package mentioned in the comments](https://github.com/hofmannmartin/SphericalHarmonicExpansions.jl). It probably has a more idiomatic approach.